# Support for `volume_mount` in Nomad Podman task driver?

Tags: docker, podman, nomad

I am doing some proof of concept work using Nomad to orchestrate several different containers running on RHEL 8 hosts using Podman. I am using the [Nomad Podman driver](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/podman) to execute my containers using Podman. I have shared state in the form of an Elasticsearch data directory that I mount into `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`.

I initially tried to get this working by defining a [host volume](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/configuration/client#host_volume) in the Nomad client configuration, then adding a [volume stanza](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/volume) that references my host volume and a [volume mount stanza](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/volume_mount) that references the volume in my Nomad job specification. That approach didn't work - no errors, but the mounting never happens.

After some digging, I found that the [Podman task driver's capabilities](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/podman#capabilities) documentation says that volume mounts are not supported. Instead, I seem to have to use the more limited driver-specific [volumes configuration](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/podman#volumes).

So my question is this: Is the lack of support for volume mounts just a temporary shortcoming that will eventually be supported? It does appear that the Docker task driver supports volume mapping and only Podman does not, so perhaps the Podman driver is just not there yet? Or is there a specific reason why there is a difference between how Docker supports volumes and how Podman does it?

Answer (score 1):

yes, currently it does not support host volume defined in nomad client section.

this will works if this PR get merge:

https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad-driver-podman/pull/152

you can build the binary uging golang in this branch:

```
git clone https://github.com/ttys3/nomad-driver-podman
git checkout append-nomad-task-mounts
./build.sh
```

replace with new generated `nomad-driver-podman` and restart nomad.